# Adding 'terms and conditions' to Infusionsoft shopping cart

Tags: opayo, infusionsoft

I want to get SagePay on my company's Infusionsoft shop. But, SagePay ask for a checkbox on the checkout to confirm that customers have read the terms and conditions. Totally understandable -  but Infusionsoft do not support this option by default.

I am not using the API. Does anyone know a way, perhaps with Javascript, that I could create such an option and NOT let customers proceed to checkout without clicking 'accept'?

Thanks in advance,

Nicole

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add an onclick listener for the checkout button using something like this:

```
document.getElementById("idOfButton").onclick = function(e) {

   //Look at value of checkbox

   //If checked, don't do anything
   //else e.stopPropagation
}
```

In your shopping cart theme you should be able to paste in html for the checkbox.

Comment: A bit late, thanks for taking the time to reply. Sadly, I don't understand much Javascript. 

However, I did find a solution. In case anyone else has the same issue: 
https://novaksolutions.com/tips/add-required-terms-to-your-infusionsoft-shopping-cart-or-order-form/ fixed it for me and complied with SagePay's security check